# Snapshot Agent access is denied to ReplData folder

Tags: sql-server, replication

I am setting up replication and am receiving the following error
Message: Access to the path 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\ReplData\unc' is denied.

I have set up the repl_snapshot agent and it has full access to the ReplData folder, as does my service accounts. The ReplData folder is shared.

Comment: I went ahead and changed the path to the folder and it worked fine.  Not sure what the original issue is, but I have checked all the security and it seems to be in order.